# Using scrapy to get links in Python?

Tags: python

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have absolutely no idea how to use Scrapy. I don't want to create a Scrapy crawler (or w/e), I want to incorporate it into my existing code. I've looked at the docs, but I found them a bit confusing.

What I need to do is, get links from a list on the site. I just need an example to better understand it. Also, is it possible to have a for loop to do something with each list item? They are ordered like

```
<ul>
  <li>example</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you give us the site adress and the links you need? Because its very likely to be easy to do with urllib.open and regexes or html parser

Comment: I can't, first of all it's... illegal in a way, and next thing is you have to be staff to access the page.

Comment: @Kingpin "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." -- It's worth keeping in mind; chances are that you can scrape the website with regular python, regexes are not the end-all-be-all of website parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider BeautifulSoup, which is great for parsing HTML/XML, their [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) is quite helpful as well. Getting the links would be something like:

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.nytimes.com')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_key('href'):
        print link['href']
```

SoupStrainer removes the need to parse the entire thing when all you're after are the links.

**EDIT:** Just saw that you need to use Scrapy. I'm afraid I've not used it, but try looking at the official [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors), it looks like they have what you might be after.

Comment: Your code is throwing `  File "testy.py", line 9
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file testy.py on line 10, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`. Please help, thanks!

Comment: @Fike it's running fine on my side, and given that my code doesn't have any non-ascii characters, it must be from somewhere else. '\xc2' is non-break space iirc (besides, my code isn't 10 lines long.

Comment: Sorry, line 9. My iPod seems to think it should create a new line when the line becomes the length of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't need scrappy if it's that simple.

```
cat local.html

<html><body>
<ul>  
<li>example</li>  
<li>example2</li>
</ul>
<div><a href="test">test</a><div><a href="hi">hi</a></div></div>
</body></html>
```

then...

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html

page =urllib2.urlopen("file:///root/local.html")
root = html.parse(page).getroot()
details = root.cssselect("li")
for x in details:
        print(x.text_content())

for x in root.xpath('//a/@href'):
        print(x)
```

Comment: I just show you two ways, one is cssselect which is simpler for people who know css and the other is xpath for the xml fans. The "html" class parses even ill-formed html code which is what you want in the general case.

Comment: But I can't use lxml, I'm running the script on an iPhone and installation of lxml is impossible. scrapy installs no problem, which is why I would rather use scrapy.

Comment: scrapy doesn't contain parsing code, it uses lxml, libxml2 or BeautifulSoup.